# Add multiple namespacs with same address to XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I need to add multiple namespaces to the xdocument with same address (C#)

```
<root xmlns:f="urn://xml.voodoo.net/vd/formating-1.0" xmlns="urn://xml.voodoo.net/vd/formating-1.0">
 <a:something>stuff and more stuff</a:something>
</root>
```

if i add using the below code.. it shows only xmlns:f

```
XNamespace defaultNS = "urn://xml.voodoo.net/vd/formating-1.0";
XNamespace f = "urn://xml.voodoo.net/vd/formating-1.0";


XElement rootElement = new XElement(defaultNS + "root",
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "f", f.NamespaceName),
```

how to show 2 namespaces?? is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement(defaultNS + "root",

        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "f", defaultNS),
        new XAttribute("xmlns", defaultNS),
        new XElement(defaultNS + "something",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "f", defaultNS), "stuff and more stuff")
            )
    );
```

Desired output:

```
<root xmlns:f="urn://xml.voodoo.net/vd/formating-1.0" xmlns="urn://xml.voodoo.net/vd/formating-1.0">
  <f:something xmlns:f="urn://xml.voodoo.net/vd/formating-1.0">stuff and more stuff</f:something>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your XML example is incorrect, the 'f' namespace is not used, whereas there is an 'a' namespace present.

Your C# code does not match your XML, it creates an element with an attribute.

Anyhow, a namespace definitions within an XML document only makes sense if you actually use it. If you create an XML document via C# code, it will generate XML which is semantically correct, yet might not match the syntax of your example.

Comment: sorry it was <f:something>stuff and more stuff</f:something>
but is it possible to have both namespaces with same http address? i need xmlns:f and xmlns with same address

Comment: What would be the point of that? namespaces are used to disambiguate xml element and attribute names. Having xmlns:f and xmlns define the same namespace is a nonsense. Remember, XML is about conveying data, it doesn't matter what it looks like!